# CR2 Photos compressing from Windows 7 to Ubuntu

Tags: file-sharing, compression, image-processing

Right now I'm going to completely move to Linux. I need to move my photos from a laptop running Windows 7 to a PC running Ubuntu. I tried sending it via Google Drive (single file, ZIP archive, RAR archive) and via USB. In all four cases Image Viewer on Ubuntu says the image is 1288x1936 (RMB >> Properties), but Picasa Photo Viewer in Windows says the image is 2602x3906. Also, the size of the file remains the same on both machines: 9,287,417 bytes. The photos are in the 'CR2' format (Canon Raw Image). Why do images get compressed?

Sending a JPEG image via Google Drive resulted in the same image size. Maybe Picasa Photo Viewer or Ubuntu's Image Viewer treats the 'CR2' format wrong?

Converting this photo from CR2 to JPEG in Windows (through a website) makes it 1288x1936, just as Linux says.

Answer (score 1):

The image viewer shows the preview image which is embedded in the RAW file and tells correctly its size. Also, the website is not converting the raw, it just extracts the preview image.

You don't need a webtool to extract the preview, you can do the same yourself with `ufraw`:

Install:

```
sudo apt install ufraw
```

Extract thumbnail:

```
ufraw --embedded-image FILENAME.CR2
```

for all files in the current folder:

```
ufraw-batch --embedded-image *.CR2
```

---

Generally speaking, camera raw formats are not made for viewing, thus showing the preview image is the right thing to do for an image viewer.

For "real" converting the raw images in full size, you need a raw converter, e.g. [Darktable](https://darktable.org), [Rawtherapee](http://rawtherapee.com/) or [ufraw](http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/). 
You can install all of these from Ubuntu Software.

Note that you need a lot of time, experience and practice to get everything out of your Photos. Otherwise you might be unhappy with the results. Maybe you should better tell your camera to save the shots directly in JPEG or get the best of both worlds saving both RAW and JPEG (this is what I am doing).

Comment: Is there a difference between `ufraw` and `ufraw-batch` commands?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure, I even believe the second command with just ufraw would work the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to convert my CR2 photos to JPG format. Instead of websites or something you should use Photoshop as it appears to have its own tool for opening CR2 images and then among other things saving it to JPG without this weird compression. Still don't know why this compression takes place, but at least now I have my photos at the best possible resolution.

By the way, Photoshop produced a bit brighter image than websites, but that's not much of a deal and can be easily fixed if you want (I do not).